# How to import a mixed tab and comma delineated ASCII file in R

Tags: r

I have an ASCII file that includes a set of MODIS data containing a series of pixel values for each acquisition date. The data format is:

- ASCII values are comma delimited
- Data values start after header rows and are space delimited.

An example of two dates from the data is shown below:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
MODIS HDF Tile                     MOD13Q1.A2003273.h11v03.005.2008260032604.hdf
Scientific Data Set (Band)         250m_16_days_EVI
Number of Values Passing QA Filter 81 of 81
Applying the Scale of .0001        MEAN: 0.24070987654321, STD-DEV: 0.0257345931611507 
Unscaled                           MEAN: 2407.0987654321, STD-DEV: 257.345931611507


2213,2160,2206,2408,2369,2362,2423,2466,2318,2160,2429,2316,2260,2362,2431,2172,2021,2254,2424,2391,2427,2331,1934,2220,2235,2254,2186,2325,2046,1956,2273,2220,2235,2257,2425,2534,2141,2288,2273,2263,2436,2568,2603,2470,2561,2288,2369,2628,2725,2730,2603,2704,2744,2732,2624,2606,2694,2730,2718,2765,2771,2732,2771,2726,2694,2637,2699,2806,2712,2384,1904,1982,2747,2788,2610,2647,2408,2096,1946,1858,1791


----------------------------------------------------------------------------
MODIS HDF Tile                      MOD13Q1.A2003289.h11v03.005.2008263131227.hdf
Scientific Data Set (Band)          250m_16_days_EVI
Number of Values Passing QA Filter  81 of 81
Applying the Scale of .0001         MEAN: 0.261756790123457, STD-DEV: 0.0232843291670261 
Unscaled                            MEAN: 2617.56790123457, STD-DEV: 232.843291670261


2074,2323,2382,2574,2614,2661,2631,2599,2525,2399,2548,2545,2541,2599,2415,2428,2417,2518,2549,2471,2539,2520,2407,2358,2426,2461,2575,2427,2412,2518,2500,2394,2509,2567,2569,2648,2414,2573,2498,2626,2509,2708,2694,2654,2702,2536,2750,2804,2917,2926,2942,2938,2844,2839,2863,2985,3006,2991,2997,2937,2830,2838,2607,3101,3093,3085,2950,2881,2608,2570,2499,2233,2912,2833,2819,2348,2426,2541,2243,2239,2071
```

A typical ASCII file has about 900 dates included i.e. 900 "tiles" of information in exactly the same format as listed above, on after another. The number of pixels is the same in each i.e. 81 values for each date.

What i would like to do is to read in the file and for each date, extract the "MODIS HDF Tile" name e.g. MOD13Q1.A2003289.h11v03.005.2008263131227.hdf and each pixel value to individual columns, something like:

```
MODIS HDF Tile                                 Scientific Data Set (Band) V2    V3    V4     V5    V6    V7...
MOD13Q1.A2003273.h11v03.005.2008263131227.hdf  250m_16_days_ENVI         2213  2160  2206   2408  2369 .......
MOD13Q1.A2003289.h11v03.005.2008263131227.hdf  250m_16_days_ENVI         2074  2323  2382   2574  2614 .....
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you probably need to put together a custom function using `readLines()` to grab the whole file (unless it's enormous); `grep` to locate the boundaries between tiles; and then `scan/read.table/strsplit` to pick out the bits you want.

Comment: Does each chunk contain 8 lines of text and a separation line (`-----`)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this could work

```
modis <- readLines("modis.txt")
headers <- grep("^MODIS", modis)

headtiles <- sapply(strsplit(modis[headers[1]],"\\s{2,}"), '[',1 )
headbands <- sapply(strsplit(modis[headers[1]+1],"\\s{2,}"), '[',1 )

tiles <- sapply(strsplit(modis[headers],"\\s{2,}"), '[',2 )
bands <- sapply(strsplit(modis[headers+1],"\\s{2,}"), '[',2 )

pxlines <- grep("(,.*?){5,}", modis)
pixels <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(modis[pxlines], ","), as.numeric))

dd<-data.frame(tiles, bands, pixels)
names(dd)<-c(headtiles , headbands , paste0("pixel", seq.int(ncol(pixels))))
```

Here we grep through all the lines to find the header line, then we assume the next line is the band line. And then we look for lines with lots of commas for the pixel values. This is making a lot of assumptions about the data file based on the limited sample you provided.